# Scaling and positioning relative to screen size

Tags: ios, xcode8, ios-autolayout

I've been looking at many differnent solutions using size classes and Autolayout and still haven't been able to get a consistent UI on different sized screens. This seems like it would be a pretty trivial thing to do but I'm on my second day struggling with this. I'm developing on the iPhone 7 in my story board, but when I switch preview to other devices the layouts get messed up. Here are two screen shots demonstrating the issue: [iPhone7View](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mIgTC.jpg), [iPhone4sView](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DJVX3.jpg).

What I've tried:
For the **App label**, I set the leading, trailing, verticle spacing to top layout guide, and verticle spacing from the App label to the email text field.
For the **email field** I set the leading, trailing, and verticle space to the password field.
For the **password field** I set the leading, trailing and verticle space to the sign in button.
For the **sign in button** I set the leading, trailing and verticle spacing to bottom layout guide.

Additionally, I also set the constraint so the **email** and **password** fields have the same width and height.

Is it possible to achieve this using only the storyboard, and make the views adapt to the screen size?

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible. Here's what I would do...

For the App label:

- anchor to the parent's top layout guide.
- center to parent horizontally.
- let the text determine the rest.

For the sign in/sign up button:

- anchor to parent's bottom layout guide.
- anchor to parent's leading and trailing edge.
- let the text determine the height.

For password text field:

- vertical space to sign in/sign up button
- anchor to parent's leading and trailing edge.
- fix height.

For the email text field.

- vertical space to password field
- anchor to parent's leading and trailing edge.
- fix height.

---

In response to your comment, you can't use percents with constraints in storyboard. If you want to use percents, you will have to adjust the constraints in code.

Another option would be to use a stack view. Here is an example:

https://www.dropbox.com/s/d7yfgjvafweqykq/example.storyboard?dl=0

Comment: Following your instructions, this is what I got. Not exactly what I was looking for. [iPhone7](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B348SRfrfzY2aGlIUnNvSldRZ1E/view?usp=sharing) [iPhone4s](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B348SRfrfzY2ZFZYNVJoLWtRbUE/view?usp=sharing).  How can I make the label, button, and anchor to parent's bottom/top layout guide based on the screen size? That seems to be a problem on different sized screens.

Comment: So for example, how can I specify that the button lies 10% above the bottom edge of the screen? No matter the screen size.

Comment: I downloaded your Storyboard and it looks great. However, when I tried to replicate your Storyboard for learning purposes I was unable to. Specifically, I was unable to resize anything within the stack view. I added a stack view and anchored it to parent's top & bottom layout guide as well as leading and trailing edge. Then I added a label and view inside the stack view. I was unable to resize either of these and so they both take up the entire stack view. How were you able to resize the label and view so that they each took up 50% of the verticle screen?

Comment: Make sure the stack views `distribution` property in the storyboard is set to `Fill Equally`.

Comment: I changed the `distribution` property from `Fill` to `Fill Equally` but still was not able to adjust the label dimensions from filling the entire stack view. I really appreciate all you help thus far.

Comment: You can't adjust the dimensions of views inside a stack view. The stack view decides what size they will be. In order to get a view to fill half the stack view, you have to set it to Fill Equally *and* put two views in it. Stack views are an odd sort of beast, they derive from UIView but they aren't really UIViews. I suggest you read some tutorials about them.

Comment: Wow, that fixed it. I can't believe how simple that was. Thank you for all your help!

Answer (score 0):

I would lower the priority of the fixed constant constraints, and then create another set of more flexible constraints for the minimum spacing that you want.

As an example of what I mean, for the App Name label you would keep the original top space constraint that you have, but lower the priority to, say, 750. You would then create another constraint for the top spacing and make it something like >= 40 (whatever you want the minimum spacing to be), and the priority for this should be higher than that original constraint (i.e. keep it at 1000).